# Elasticsearch - how to aggregate on wildcard field

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate, wildcard

I dont know if thats possible, but Ive filter for locality using * wildcard, fe.: find all rows with locality: 0010020*. That returns 3000 rows (0010020 (2000 rows) for city and 001002001 (1000 rows) for city discrict).

Term aggregation on "locality" returns 0010020 - 2000 rows. Is that a possibility to say to aggregation "count with wildcard" and return all 3000 rows as doc_count?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this , Use `query_string` instead of `wildcard` .`query_string` is more powerful than `wildcard`:-

```
{
    "_source": false,
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "fields": ["fieldName"],
            "query": "*fieldValue1* *fieldValue2*"
        }
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "byFieldName": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "fieldName"
            }
        }
    }
}
```